# Замена двойного бэкслэша в пути файла в переменной Python

Tags: python, replace

получил путь в переменную
nfile = event.src_path
Путь получися вида `'C:\\Work\\export\\121.txt'`

Нужно заменить \\ на \

`nfile = nfile.replace('\\','\')` не помогло.

ОС - Windows10

Пока заработало через такой код:

```
    path = r"C:\work\export\\"
    nfile = event.src_path
    fname = str(nfile).split('\\')[-1:][0]
    fullname = path + fname
    with open(fullname) as file:
        rline = file.read()
```

Но мне кажется это через ...
Подскажите как правильнее оформить данный момент

Comment: `nfile = nfile.replace('\\','/')` почему не так ?

Comment: Используйте модуль `pathlib`

Comment: nfile = nfile.replace('\\','/')  - ос windows

Comment: Не нужно заменять. Нужно почитать про экранирование символов и научиться пользоваться подходящим модулями.

Comment: Можно использовать / вместо \\  , но разницы никакой нет)

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно ничего менять: каждый удвоенный обратный слеш внутри кавычек - это по факту один символ. Убедиться в этом можно, если вывести строку через print:

```
print('C:\\Work\\export\\121.txt')  # Выведет C:\Work\export\121.txt
```

Удвоение внутри строк нужно из-за того, что некоторые сочетания со слешем внутри строки имеют специальное значение, например `'\n'` (перенос строки), `'\r'` ("возврат каретки", т.е. сдвиг курсора на начало строки), `'\b'` ("забой", он же backspace - сдвиг курсора на один символ влево) и т.д. Чтобы отличить, например, два отдельных символа - обратный слеш и букву n, от одного символа переноса строки нужно удвоить обратный слеш, т.е. `'\n'` - один символ, а `'\\n'` - два символа.

Если использовать r-строки, то удваивать обратный слеш внутри кавычек не нужно. Фактически две строки ниже равны между собой:

```
>>> 'C:\\Work\\export\\121.txt' == r'C:\Work\export\121.txt'                    
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю что у тебя не получилось.
[image: у меня всё получилось]
OC - xubuntu
IDLE - PyCharm PythonConsole
python - 3.7

```
nfile.replace('\\', '/')
```

Comment: ОС - Windows, извините не уточнил сразу

Comment: я проверил на компьютере с windows 10 и python 3.7.6 тоже заработало  
к сожалению скриншоты скинуть не могу

Comment: В windows срабатывает, в windows путь чрез обратный слэш \